# Using tee command with soft linked file

Tags: linux, symlink, tee

I have a script start.sh which runs another script run.sh. run.sh starts my executable.

I wanted to record what run.sh does and I used a tee command to log it into a file loglink, start.sh:

```
exec run.sh | tee -a loglink
```

loglink is a **soft linked file**.

I have a logic where I have 3 log files log1.txt log2.txt log3.txt, I need each file to have a max size of only 1024 bytes. So in my code I keep checking every 5 seconds if log1.txt has reached max size, if reached max size, I change the softlink loglink to point to log2.txt, same with log2.txt and log3.txt in circular way.

As per my understanding, when I change the softlink from log1.txt to log2.txt, tee should print to log2.txt, but strange, tee is still saving output to log1.txt and not log2.txt

And to add on,
I see the softlink changed in ls -l
I tried something `ls-l | tee loglink`, it does to log2.txt.

Why the tee in script start.sh is not recognising this link change?
Am I missing some logic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, a filename or symbol link is just a proxy for program to tell the kernel setup the reading or writing path for the real file representation in kernel.

tee used `file descriptor` to represent files, as its source code(from freebsd) explains:

```
for (exitval = 0; *argv; ++argv)
        if ((fd = open(*argv, append ? O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND :
            O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, DEFFILEMODE)) < 0) {
            warn("%s", *argv);
            exitval = 1;
        } else
            add(fd, *argv);
```

once a file is opened, in your case, the symbol link is followed and open the target log file, after then, the path for writing do file is opened, and symbol link or filename is not need anymore.

Answer (score 0):

A program which opens a file keeps that file link. If you change the link from outside, the program is not impressed and keeps writing to (or reading from) the original file.

Only if your program closes the file and reopens it, it will be using the new link.

You may, for example, open a file in vlc and play it, then, while playing, move it to a different directory. No problem. Then delete it. You now can't open it with a new program, but the old one is using it until the file is closed by that program.

Comment: So i should close the file that the softlink is pointing to , before i change the link from program?

Comment: Yes. You could append to the log, line by line, and close/reopen it for every line, for being able to swap the file, the link is pointing to.

Comment: i dint get this , close/reopen for everyline? how can i do it with tee command
exec run.sh | tee -a loglink 
All i can do is before changing the link in my code, i can close log1.txt and link with log2.txt. Will this work?

Comment: You can't with the tee command. You only specify a file once there. How would you close log1.txt?

Comment: i tried doing from code .. fopen fclose of log1.txt.. Not much helpful.. loglink is still pointing to same

Comment: fopen() fclose() loop will work for sure. Each fopen() will reread current link location and open proper file.

Answer (score 0):

Its a normal behaviour, as rightly explained in other answers. 
As a solution you should periodically `open` and `close` output file in your `run.sh` or use
very nice [utility](https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect/)  for runtime change of the other process output:

```
 reredirect  -m newfile.log  `pidof run.sh`
```